# Add a new row or spaces to output space or a new row

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

i need help with adding space or a new row in a script. It looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {

 var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
 var sender = message.getFrom();
 var body = "This email is sent from:" + " " + sender + message.getPlainBody();
 var subject = message.getSubject();
 var attachment = message.getAttachments();
 GmailApp.sendEmail("user.name@aruba.com", subject, body, {attachments: attachment});

}
```

I need to add the `"message.getPlainBody();"` on a new line under the `"This email is sent from:" + " " + sender "`

Right now all gets on the same row in the Email. Is there any similar thing like the html tag `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert [linebreak/newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_character) characters in strings to start a new line.
Note the **\n** which actually counts as 1 character (the \ starts an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Programming_languages))

```
var body = "This email is sent from:\n" + sender + "\n\n" + message.getPlainBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with adding `\n`:

```
var body = "This email is sent from: " + sender + "\n" + message.getPlainBody();
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect, do you know if i can make the text bold ?

Comment: @user3432918 Just use HTML `<b>` tags.